# How we can get clicked date to next page in Jquery UI Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fullcalendar

This is Full Calendar div:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

This is Full Calendar Script:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    var date = new Date(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        started,
        categoryClass;

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,

      select: function(start, end, allDay) {

        $('#fc_create').click();

        started = start;
        ended = end;          

        //alert(started);// return click dates

        $(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
          var title = $("#title").val();
          if (end) {
            ended = end;
          }

          categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

          if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: title,
                start: started,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
              },
              true // make the event "stick"
            );
          }

          $('#title').val('');

          calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

          $('.antoclose').click();

          return false;
        });

      },

      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#fc_edit').click();
        $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);

        categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

        $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function() {
          calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();

          calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
          $('.antoclose2').click();
        });

        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
      },

      editable: true,

      events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
      }, {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
      }, {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
        allDay: false
      }, {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 14, 12, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
        allDay: false
      }, {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        allDay: false
      }, {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        url: 'http://google.com/'
      }]


    });

  });
</script>
<!-- /FullCalendar -->
```

Everything is perfect but the problem is how i can post started variable on another page for usage php script. The commented alert activate when we click
a particular date.

Comment: You can put selected date in a hidden input box then when it is submitted the values get send to php script if you are using form method. otherwise, you can just post your values over in ajax. 

Hidden input box:
<input type = "hidden" name = "started" value =""/>

Comment: Yeah bro your trick is working thanks bro